# How to Set primary/accent colors for widgets for entire application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

My base theme file for application is following wherein i am setting the primary colors and the accent colors

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_yellow</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_yellow_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_orange</item>
</style>
```

However when i am using the editext and switches as well as the radio buttons i am getting the stock blue color for the widgets when it is pressed or when it's state has changed.All i want is to change to the primary color which is set in my `styles.xml`.Also as i am targeting devices greater than `API16`,i want uniform support across all devices upto API22

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT

Using the themes for entire aplication like this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme,android:icon">
```

Comment: can u post your manifest ?

Comment: posted only the application tag in which i am using the theme

Comment: From my experience that seems to be all fine. I would suggest to go back to the AppCompat blog post and double check all the details: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Comment: are you using the AppCompatActivity ??

Comment: Nope i am using the ActionBarActivity as i am using toolbar.Should i use AppCompatActivity?

Comment: that blog post I show u the link goes into great length explaining why `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated and the new thing is `AppCompatActivity`. And they're a direct replacement of each other in your code (it uses the toolbar the same way). So I give it a try.

Comment: Those two are *almost* functionally equivalent. AppCompatActivity is the new one, and should be used for new Apps.

Comment: Okay will try that and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution i created two styles.xml files one for API21 and above and one for API16 and above.In that added added these two lines to the base theme

```
<!--used for changing the focius colors of editext-->
 <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_yellow</item>
 <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_yellow</item>
```